# What is the lump on top of the Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737

What are the lumps (Circled) on top of these two Boeing 737s? I looked it up but I only found the answer for one specific Virgin Blue 737.

[image]

Original image [source](http://www.jetphotos.net/photo/8165291)

Comment: [Also more info about wifi on aircraft](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14849/1696)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the antenna for the [inflight wifi system](http://gizmodo.com/every-major-airlines-wifi-service-explained-and-ranked-1701017977). The Southwest aircraft has a Ku band antenna on the top, allowing it to access the internet through satellites. The United aircraft appears to have a similar system.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like satellite data link antenna [discussed here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11762/524). It provides internet connection for passengers.