# What's this prominience in the B737?

Tags: airliner, boeing-737, feature-identification

I have recovered some spotting pictures that I made long ago and I came to realize an upper prominence in the fuselage of this Norwegian Boeing 737. I don't remember to have seen it in other 737s.

**Does anyone know what is it and its purpose?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also [What is the lump on top of the Boeing 737?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25903/14897)

Comment: What is the lump on top of the Boeing 737? Indeed, this one asks for the same feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a SATCOM (Satellite COMmunication) antenna. It has several purposes, one of them is internet connection for the passengers.

There are different types and configurations. On some aircraft the antenna is in the front, on some it's in the back, some have two.

(image from http://www.b737.org.uk/latest-2016-04-06.htm)

[image]

Comment: I think that article refers only to specific a application. Most B737s don’t need Satcom communication as they are almost always line of sight with the ground. Most of those large antennas on the roof are for WiFi only. Most overseas aircraft has Satcom long before these WiFi antennas were installed.